# Поиск искажённой строки в списке истинных строк

Tags: c#, строки, list, search

Дано:

1. Список/массив List со истиными строками порядка 200-300шт. Строки длиной не более 20 символов.
   Например:

**diablo1981**

**eaterr**

**prikol77**

2. Строка поиска, которая может быть искажена случайным образом, или же полностью соответствовать одному из элементов списка.
   Например, строка может 100% совпадать с одной из истинных строк **diablo1981**.
   А может быть и искажена:

**diabloI98l**

**priko111**

**eat err**

Задача найти и вернуть среди истинных строк максимально похожую на искаженную строку.

Подскажите каким наиболее простым и быстрым способом можно это реализовать?

Comment: [Расстояние Левенштейна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0)?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1421438/184217 - посмотрите ответы и комментарии